# AddressBookManager using 100% CPU

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My macbook pro running OSX 10.7.3 will fire up the heavy fans even if left idle with all major apps closed. In Activity Monitor, AddressBookManager is shown as taking 110% CPU, even though I have only two address in my address book (mine and apple's) and I never open the application.

I can kill AddressBookManager from Activity Monitor, but it comes back again in a few minutes.

I still have loads of free memory, and the disk doesn't seem to be being thrashed, it's just the CPU usage. I probably wouldn't even notice if it wasn't for the fans.

Suggested from the comments, here's the accounts in my address book preferences:

[image]

As you can see, nothing there untoward.

Thanks in advance and for the help already.

Comment: Do you have iCloud enabled?

Comment: No. Every time I open settings it prompts me to set it up and I ignore it. :)

Comment: In your address book prefs, look under Accounts. Is there anything more listed there than "on my mace" local? I'm sure there are other things address book manager does like allow the address book information to be inherited by other applications on your Mac but given that you're not actively using it I'm stumped as to why there's activity.

Comment: @Richard Good suggestion as I haven't actually looked in that window, but as you can see, no luck.

Comment: Two years later, and I never solved this problem. It was a work laptop and I changed it for another one six months later. Haven't had the problem re-appear on the new one.

Comment: @tenpn, in the 2 years do you re-install the os x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue:

1. Export your AddressBook information if necessary.(I did not, because I have no import information in AddressBook)
2. Go to this directory `/Users/luowensheng/Library/Application\ Support/`
3. Delete the `AddressBook` directory, if there is synchronization, it may come back, do not care of that.
4. So, you can see the Activity monitor, does the AddressBookManager still high? if still high,  delete the `AddressBook` directory more times.

[image]

Comment: can't check your answer as I no longer have the problem laptop, but you can have the tick for now!

Comment: @tenpn This real works for me.